# Facebook login with redirect URL

Tags: facebook, redirect, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am developing a Facebook canvas appliaction, and I am trying to do the following, which is standard in many applications.

- User arrives on my application page.
- If he has not granted the necessary permissions, he is redirected to a page where he can (optionally authenticate) and accept the permissions, and
- finally redirected back to my facebook application page.

As far as I understand, this is achieved by redirecting the user to the [OAuth dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/), on

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?
  scope=PERMISSIONS&
  client_id=CLIENT_ID&
  redirect_uri=MY_CANVAS_URL&
  response_type=token
```

The problem is that Facebook will not allow a redirect from inside an iframe, for security reasons. It only allows redirects to what I declare as `site URL` on the application settings page. In my case I have set that to the URL of the application on Facebook, since that is what I put as `redirect_uri` (and it works).

So, instead of being able to see the authentication dialog, the user is presented only a link to it. A kind of workaround is to issue the redirect with javascript, by manually settings `top.location`. But this is not a real solution, since part of the site already shows before Javascript redirects, and I get an annoying flicker.

> What is the correct way to obtain this flow?

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with the above flow? most apps use it and the users are used to it.

Comment: The flow is fine, I'm not sure how to achieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use:

```
top.location.href=myAuthUrl;
```

There is a tutorial on canvas auth here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/#auth

Comment: As I have written in the question itself, I am already doing this. I am not completely satisfied, though, because the application page is visible for a fraction of a second before the redirect happens, unlike what would happen with a server-side redirect.

Comment: Although it isn't a direct solution as you are looking for, you maybe could hide, or not load, your content until you have confirmed that the user is logged in and authed etc. I think even with a server redirect, you will still be redirecting within the frame which won't work. The 'correct way' does seem to be the top.location solution, as described on facebook's own tutorial page. I would be interested in any other solution as I had the same issue myself.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a validation page before you redirect to your app home page .
something like this :

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="facebook_javascript_api_file_src"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
        function verify(){
        FB.init({
                appId:"app_id",
                status:true,
                cookie:true,
                xfbml:true
                }

        );

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
                    if(response.session){
                         top.location.href="url to your app home page";
                    }
                    else{
                         top.location.href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/  
         oauth?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=redirect_url&scope=email,read_stream";
                     }
        })
    }
        verify();
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```